# How can I create simple text-based graphics in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

Example:

[image: example]

Is it possible to create such lines and the two little things as the image shows? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Your question should really stand on its own. The title should be something like “Can I create simple images of text with lines in bash”?

Comment: That depends on the terminal (emulator) and the supported character set.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Are you trying to create such an *image* or create a facsimile of such an image with text in the terminal?

Comment: I use GNOME...so far I've been able to create two horizontal lines. but not the two little things in between.

Comment: @Emmet: I tried to do the latter

Comment: He's trying to copy spritz: http://www.spritzinc.com/

Comment: @user3254019 same thing in perl [here](https://github.com/pasky/speedread)

Comment: @Valerij: thanks buti honestly dont understand Perl:(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to build an image, with use of external tools (bash has no built-in graphics APIs). As examples, you could:

- Use XMLStarlet to build a SVG file describing the graphic you want, and invoke Inkscape in command-line mode to render it to a file (`.png`, etc).
- Use GraphicsMagick in command-line mode (with the `-draw` argument to the `convert` command).

If, by contrast, you want to render that image to the terminal, you can use your terminal font's available line-drawing characters and color support, but will not have the same level of detailed control (ability to select fonts, select pixel-specific locations, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what i wanted to do was not to build an image. I just simply looked for commands to create those lines and tees and put them together like the image

Comment: @user3254019, if what you want is ASCII graphics, well, that's the phrase to use / search for / &c. That said, it's generally a bad idea -- not all terminals behave the same way, and it's easy to build something that works for you but messes up someone else's terminal; that's why folks building this kind of thing in more capable languages have libraries like ncurses to abstract away the details.

Comment: If you're really insistent, though, see the 'tput' library to look up color codes... and ideally, if you can get away with only supporting new terminals, use Unicode line-drawing characters. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

Comment: Thanks so much for the link. That's exactly what i've been looking for

Comment: @user3254019, I have another answer going into more detail on that topic. (Leaving this one as-is, as it might be useful for someone who actually *does* want to generate PNG files).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the list of characters in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character

If your user supports a Unicode-aware terminal, then, you could do something like:

```
printf '\u2500\u252c\u2500\nf%sO%so\n\u2500\u2534\u2500\n' \
  "$(tput setf red)" "$(tput setf black)"
```

The `\u2500`s  get replaced with horizontal bars, the `\u252c` with a horizontal bar with a tee pointing down, the `\u2534` with a horizontal bar with a tee pointing up, etc.

The `%s`s get replaced with corresponding arguments -- `"$(tput setf red)"` to make the foreground text red (or no character at all, if the current terminal doesn't support color), the `"$(tput setf black)"`... well, does the obvious thing.

Comment: I think using `\uXXXX` to specify Unicode code points is new in `bash` 4; older versions will need to specify the UTF8 bytes explicitly: `printf '\xe2\x94\x80...'`