# Print every word in a text file onto the screen once at a time

Tags: bash, shell

My text file contains this line:

```
ten forty twenty fifty sixty two eleven thin
```

I want to write a script to go through the text file and output only one word once on the screen.

For example: print the word `ten` and then `forty` (`ten` already disappeared), etc.

Answer (score 6):

Is this what you mean?

```
while read line; do
    for word in ${line}; do
        printf "\r\033[0K${word}"
        sleep 0.5
    done
done < words.txt
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i looked for. Thanks for your answer. BTW, can you explain a bit what the printf line means?

Comment: @user3254019 The `\r` is a carriage return which places the cursor at the beginning of the current line. `\033[0K` prints an [ANSI sequence](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) which deletes from the current cursor position to the end of the line.

Comment: @UserFriendly In conjunction with your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22408843/1126841), you may need something more sophisticated than simply returning the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Can you give me an example of that? I've been  stuck on that thing for the past 5 hours

Comment: @UserFriendly Let me guess, you are trying to re-implement spreeder? There are already command-line implementations out there, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @Adrian: I could not seem to find bash-related implementations, I'd be more than happy if you shared any links of those things with me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear the screen:

```
echo "ten forty twenty fifty sixty two eleven thin" | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '{system("sleep 1;clear");print}'
```

or

```
cat foo.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '{system("sleep 1;clear");print}'
```

In order to have 2 words at once:

```
cat foo.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '{print;system("sleep 1;clear");print}'
```

PS: `\r\033[0K` go to the beginning of the line and delete to the end of the line